# calculating probabilities from transition matrix without calculating left eigenvector

Tags: stochastic-processes, self-learning, transition-matrix

Consider a  markov chain with transition probability matrix given by

\begin{bmatrix}0.5 &0.5 & 0 \\0&0.5&0.5\\0.33 &0.33&0.33     \end{bmatrix}

let $p^n_{ij}$ denote n-step transition probability from state i to state j then 
without calculating left eigenvector show that

$1.\lim_{n\to\infty}p^n_{11}= \frac{2}{9}
$  and

$2.\lim_{n\to\infty}p^n_{13}= \frac{1}{3}
$

i only know how to solve it using left eigen vector , but i am not able to think of quicker way to solve  this .

Comment: Is computing $P^n$ directly fair game?

Comment: @amd can you please elaborate what you just said